# Download PHP ZipArchive returns corrupt, blank zip file

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I've had a look at various threads about ZipArchive and how to get files to download. However, I've gotten a bit stuck here.
I currently have a form that looks like this

```php
<form name="download-resources" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="download-resources" value="1" />
    <?php foreach($resources as $key => $value) { ?>
        <label for="<?php echo $value->name; ?>"><?php echo $value->name; ?> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="download-items[<?php echo $key; ?>]" download-id="<?php echo $key; ?>" /></label>
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Download"/>
</form>
```

Within that form, are some aspects that come from the rest of the script, which is here:

```php
<?php

$resources = array();

// Create our items
$i = 1;
while($i <= 3) {
    ${'item-' . $i} = new stdClass();
    ${'item-' . $i}->name = 'item-' . $i;
    ${'item-' . $i}->link = 'link';
    $resources[$i] = ${'item-' . $i};
    $i++;
}

// When we post the form
if(!empty($_POST['download-resources'])) {
    $archive_file_name = 'some resources.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
        foreach($_POST['download-items'] as $key => $value) {
            $zip->addFile('https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt', 'test.txt');
            //$zip->addFile(${'item-' . $key}->link . '.txt');
        }
        $zip->close();
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }

    header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name");
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($archive_file_name));
    readfile("$archive_file_name");
    exit;
}

?>
```

I've tested all of the other bits, like the generation of the objects and such. But currently I'm just puzzled at why the files won't download properly. Whenever I hit the submit button to download, after selecting one or two of the items, I get given a zip file with the correct zip name - all fine and dandy. But when attempting to open the file using WinRaR, the following message appears:

> The archive is either in unknown format or damaged

I have attempted the old trick of opening the zip file in notepad to try and see whether there are any errors present. However, the result that returns is completely blank, which is really weird to me.

Does anyone know how I might fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove your `echo`'s. You can't output _anything at all_ except the file data. If you do, then it will be part of the downloaded file, which will corrupt it.

Comment: Hi. Do you mean every single echo in the script (including those in the form) or just the ones in the post handling area? I've just removed the latter and it hasn't changed anything about the corruption.

Comment: Make sure the posted download code is in its own file and submit your form to it. Then you remove `echo 'ok';` and `echo 'failed';` from the code (those will always mess up the downloaded file). Those `echo`'s should also cause a bunch of "headers already sent"-warnings (one for each "header") since  `header()` _must_ be called before _any_ output as well. If errors/warnings are displayed on the screen, then those warnings would also be part of the final output (which would also corrupt the downloaded file). All output will be added to the downloaded file.

Comment: Okay so I've separated the content. The lines from "if(!empty($_POST['download-resources'])) {" to "exit; }" is now in a new file, and that is now the post action of the form. Still nothing. The form will download a zip that is corrupt, with nothing in it.

Comment: Have you tried adding local _files_, instead of URLs? Even if we assume that `addFile` supports using URLs, you never know what might go wrong when your server tries to request content via HTTP from elsewhere on the web.

Comment: Did you also remove the `echo`'s in that code?

Comment: @CBroe unfortunately I've already given that a go. The line that has the external file was originally `$zip->addFile($SERVER['DOCUMENT-ROOT'] . '/technology/tony/test.txt','test.txt');`. That hasn't worked either.

Comment: @M.Eriksson yes. In the script that the form actions (the new download-zip.php), there are no echos whatsoever.

Comment: Regarding what @CBroe suggested. There is another approach. You can simply read the file contents of the external file and store it in a variable: (`$data = file_get_contents('https://www....');`) and add it to the zip using [ZipArchive::addFromString()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php)

Comment: How big is the file you've downloaded? Does the file size seem sensible, or is it too small? Btw, you're attempting to download the zip file even if it failed to create it, which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: The file size is 0 every time I try. Is it an ordering issue with where my statements are? I have the close inside the open if statement, should that be outside?

As for the string solution, doesn't work either. I've tried moving the text file to a "files" directory, and then creating a variable `$files = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/technology/tony/files');` and inside the zip open statement `foreach($files as $file) {$zip->addFromString(basename($file), file_get_contents($file));}`

Comment: After you called the `close` method, `some resources.zip` should physically exists on your server, in the current working directory. Have you checked whether that was the case, via FTP? And if so, what happens when you download that file _via FTP_?

Comment: Does the file have to store something? I'm currently working off of a server at work. Didn't think the zip file would need to store anywhere before a download. Is that how the ziparchive function works? Needs to run off of an existing file? What's the point of creating a ziparchive if it needs to have a pre-existing one. Thought this was just the solution for bundling files in a zip and sending it to the user.

Comment: `$archive_file_name = 'some resources.zip';`, when inserted in `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name");`, is not going to result in a very sensible value. You should put the `filename` value into double quotes here.

Comment: @CBroe you mean like `$archive_file_name = "something resources.zip";` - double quotes instead of single?

Comment: _"Didn't think the zip file would need to store anywhere before a download"_ - then where did you think `readfile("$archive_file_name")` would actually get the data from ...?

Comment: No, I mean `filename="..."` in the actual header value you are creating there. `filename=some`, followed by space, followed by random gibberish that reads `resources.zip` - that is not a value that makes much sense.

Comment: @CBroe No idea. I figured it would read the file that it's currently making in the script. I have no idea where such a temp file would be stored on the server we're running off of anyways, so might just be a server thing.

As for the filename, just changed that and hasn't done much of anything. But it's good to know at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Needed to create a temp folder, and store them there.
Here's the final solution:

```php
<?php if(!empty($_POST['download-resources'])) {
    $archive_file_name = "something resources.zip";
    $rand = rand(0,999999);
    $tmp_file = 'files/tmp/'.$rand.'.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
        foreach($_POST['download-items'] as $key => $value) {
            
            $zip->addFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/technology/tony/files/test1.txt', 'test1.txt');
            //$zip->addFile(${'item-' . $key}->link . '.txt');

        }
        $zip->close();
        header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $archive_file_name . "");
        header("Content-length: ".filesize($archive_file_name));
        readfile($tmp_file);
    } 
    exit; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will works for you.

```
// When we post the form
if (!empty($_POST['download-resources'])) {
    $archive_file_name = 'some resources.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
        foreach($_POST['download-items'] as $key => $value) {
            $file_url = 'https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt';
            $download_file = file_get_contents($file_url);
            $zip->addFromString(basename($file_url),$download_file);
            //$zip->addFile(${'item-' . $key}->link . '.txt');
        }
        $zip->close();
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }

    header("Content-type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name");
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($archive_file_name));
    readfile("$archive_file_name");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your need to choose one of methods:

1. Create temp file (via tempnam, e.g.), save to it ZipArchive, output to user and delete file.
2. Use some library that has method to create archive into string (like [NeLexa-Zip](https://github.com/Ne-Lexa/php-zip) and [outputAsString](https://github.com/Ne-Lexa/php-zip#zipfileoutputasstring))

Comment: Also, you can use my library that can create any archive type in string (in dev-master now, will be in next release) - https://github.com/wapmorgan/UnifiedArchive